# Ensure script remains installed after updates

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, mathjax

I have some script I want to add to my wordpress page (which contains Latex math, for which I use MathJax), so what I used to do is edit header.php in my themes, which is OK, except that every time I do an update, I have to edit that again and again... which is annoying and some times I forget to do that.

Is there anyway I could set that script permanently even after an update?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add this as a plugin or a widget?

Comment: @andrewsi The plugin for latex sucks and has bad graphics for the math... and it's not the only script I use.

Comment: You can create your own plugin, though, that includes the script you're already using.

Comment: @andrewsi That's an interesting idea! How do I start with that in the simplest way?

Comment: The WordPress Codex has a lot of information on this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin - if you're simply making sure that a script is added, you probably won't need more than a single file

Comment: @andrewsi Love the idea! I'm trying to do it now!

Comment: @andrewsi if you wish, post this in an answer to get the big checkmark!

Comment: I was just thinking that you should post your plugin as the answer, and accept that - all I did was provide a couple of pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to create your own plug-in, which turns our to be much simpler than anyone thinks.

1- Pick a name for your plugin, I'll call it MyPlugin

2- Open a folder in your /wp-content/plugins/MyPlugin

3- Open a file inside the latter folder and call it MyPlugin.php

4- Input the following in that file:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: MyPlugin
*/
function add_my_header() {
    echo '<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">';
    echo 'MathJax.Hub.Config({';
    echo 'tex2jax: {inlineMath: [[\'$\',\'$\']]}';
    echo '});';
    echo '</script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"';
    echo '  src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_SVG">';
    echo '</script>';
}
add_action( 'get_header', 'add_my_header' );
?>
```

You may change the script as you want.

5- Enable the plugin.

6- You're done! Give me a thumbs-up, and have fun :)

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Thanks for the info! Highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be using the [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function. This will allow you to add a script to the `wp_head()` function's output. You can place this in your functions file and it will keep the script even if you update the header.php file or the plugin. You can do this with stylesheets as well. You should also apply an action hook so that the script loads at the proper time. Here is the code:

```
function add_my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style ('style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script('script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_scripts' );
```

Note: the first argument for the functions is the unique identifier for the asset. As such, you should have a unique name for each script and style you add. You may need to use these later for dependancies or to unqueue something. The [wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) goes more into this.